# How to make an abstract function for describe in Jest, that includes several tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs, closures, puppeteer

The function Bellow works:
Taking variable 'page' from a previous beforeAll:

```
describe('describe 1', () => { test('blabla', async () => auth.login(page))})
```

I would like to have now a collection of several tests as a function, something like this:

```
const a = (page) =>  {test('blabla', async () => auth.login(page))} ;

describe('describe 3', () => a(page));
```

Unfortunately, it seems that I am not able to make it work

Answer (score 0):

It should work. E.g.

```js
const a = (page) => {
  test('blabla', () => expect(page).toBe('login'));
};

const page = 'login';

describe('describe 3', () => a(page));
```

unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60834568/index.test.ts (7.533s)
  describe 3
    ✓ blabla (2ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.474s
```